# Splitting a flink dataset into multiples by key and write to separate files

Tags: apache-flink

I would like to split my `DataSet<Tuple2<Integer, Point>>` into n DataSets according to the Integer value of the tuple2.

Currently I am basically filtering the dataset n times and save each result to a separate file. I would prefer to have a nicer and more variable way. Also this does not seem to be taking advantage of flink abilities.

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to split datasets is to use filters on the input dataset, as described here:

[Dataset split/demultiplex in Flink mailing list](http://apache-flink-mailing-list-archive.1008284.n3.nabble.com/Dataset-split-demultiplex-td11647.html)

As far as I know, there is no operator, that would do the job of splitting as you want to do it. As said in the answer, "the overhead should be reasonable. The data stays on the same node 
and the filter can be very lightweight."